# WSO2 EMM server Cannot read property "accessToken" from null

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am configuring WSO2 EMM (Ver 2.0.1) server on ubuntu (14.04) machine. All configuration look proper but when I try to authenticate on device on url

https://server-name:9443/emm-web-agent/enrollments/iOS/login-agent

Server throws error of Cannot read property "accessToken" from null

Stack trace

```
[2016-05-16 15:22:33,696] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler} -  Token request with Password Grant Type for an invalid tenant : https://server-name:9

[2016-05-16 15:22:33,785] ERROR {/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag} -  Error in obtaining token with Password grant type

[2016-05-16 15:22:33,805] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "accessToken" from null (/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag#53)

org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "accessToken" from null (/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag#53)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.invoke(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:43)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "accessToken" from null (/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag#53)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3725)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1483)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm_web_agent.modules.enrollments.ios.c2._c_script_0(/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag:53)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm_web_agent.modules.enrollments.ios.c2.call(/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm_web_agent.modules.enrollments.ios.c2.call(/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm_web_agent.modules.enrollments.ios.c2.exec(/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag)
at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
```

Comment: Have you followed the IOS configuration as instructed in the documentations and acquire an signed CSR from WSO2. If yes can you tell me the IOS feature version you have installed in your server.

Comment: Yes, we have received signed CRS. Also, this might sound novice, but where I can find iOS feature version? I have installed p2-repo folder which contains org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.ios.apns.server_2.0.2.jar, org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.ios.server_2.0.2.jar and org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.ios.web.server_2.0.2.jar. Does this mean, installed iOS feature version is 2.0.2?

Comment: Yes that is the IOS feature version and the you have installed correct version for EMM 2.0.1.
Can you provide the exact steps you had taken when this issue occurred in order to reproduce this.

Comment: I only followed the same procedure as mentioned on the site. The same one followed by another team member and got the same error.

Comment: Agreeing with inosh's comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[2016-05-16 15:22:33,696] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler} -  **Token request with Password Grant Type for an invalid tenant** : https://server-name:9
```

To me it looks like you are using a tenant that does not exist. If you don't need tenancy, do not type anything to the tenant domain field. Leave domain field blank when login in so that it uses the super tenant. Only enter the username and the password.

Comment: Now, I am trying to run the application with tenant because of profile name issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38458099/change-carbon-super-profile-service-to-custom-name. Please provide any help.