# Change "carbon.super Profile Service" to custom name

Tags: ios, wso2, mdm, wso2-iot

I am successfully able to install the WSO2 EMM profile. It's working properly on my iOS devices.

Now when I install the configuration profile for the first time it displays "carbon.super Profile Service" as profile title. How can I change the profile title?

[image: iOS WSO2 EMM Configuration Profile]

Comment: Hey @Dhiren,  have you managed to change the title and description?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is identified as a bug in the EMM, so I have created a public jira[1] for that and will be fixed soon.

[1]https://wso2.org/jira/browse/EMM-1473

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I found that WSO2 haven't open-sourced their complete source code of EMM product. I didn't find source code for ios-enrollment.war & org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.ios.payload_2.0.2.jar. Let me know if you find that. I can replace the individual components also if there is source code.

Comment: Hi Dhiren, WSO2 iOS plugin contains propitiatory code which is not able to distribute under open source license. So there is no any open source code available from WSO2 for public which is relevant to iOS. That is why you can't find any relevant sources for iOS related implementations.

Comment: Please make iOS code also open-source. The open-source community will greatly help to improve the product. Right now it looks like wso2emm product is seating on the pile of bugs.

Comment: Hey @Charitha, have you managed to change the title and description?