# WSO2 EMM: Error in obtaining token with Password grant type

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

EMM Build: 2.0.1
OS: RHEL 7.2 (x64)

Issue:

I am in the middle of the enrollment for an IOS device and during step 2, when it asks for domain/username and password, when I hit submit, I receive the following error:

HTTPS Status 500 - org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: Cannot read property "accessToken" from null (/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag#53)

The stack trace is:

`[2016-08-10 19:24:46,500] ERROR {/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag} -  Error in obtaining token with Password grant type
[2016-08-10 19:24:46,501] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "accessToken" from null (/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag#53)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "accessToken" from null (/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag#53)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.invoke(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:43)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "accessToken" from null (/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag#53)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3687)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3693)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3712)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3725)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1483)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm_web_agent.modules.enrollments.ios.c0._c_script_0(/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag:53)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm_web_agent.modules.enrollments.ios.c0.call(/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm_web_agent.modules.enrollments.ios.c0.call(/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.emm_web_agent.modules.enrollments.ios.c0.exec(/emm-web-agent/modules/enrollments/ios/agent-controller.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)`

I have configured the tenant and provisioned the tenant's admin user. I am logging into EMM as the tenant's admin user and attempting to enroll the device as this user.

I've also tried skipping the domain during registration (leaving it blank as was suggested in this issue: [WSO2 EMM server Cannot read property "accessToken" from null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257848/wso2-emm-server-cannot-read-property-accesstoken-from-null)) but it's not working.

I have attempted this both as a super domain admin as well as the tenant admin and both times, it's failed.

Any ideas what may be causing this? Please help...Thanks!

Comment: Can you check whether you can enroll your device using the default 'admin', 'admin' username and password? (Keep the domain field blank) ?

Comment: I originally tried that as the other similar issue that was posted here suggested to do that. When leaving the "domain" field blank and providing the admin creds, I get an error in the IOS Enrollment page that says, "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again."

Answer (score 0):

Please Use the tenant domain of users tenant for the domain field in the agent login screen if you are using a tenant user account for the enrollment.

Keeping the tenet domain filed empty is only acceptable if you are using a user account from the super tenant.

Comment: I tried this previously (logging in and trying enrolling as the tenant admin) and it resulted in the same error but I just went back to confirm/double-check and it does indeed generate the same error. 

Trying to enroll as admin in the super domain also does not work because leaving the domain blank generates the "An Unexpected Error Occurred. Please Try Again."     

Please advise as I need to get this enrollment process working.